# Font from external website not loading in firefox

Tags: firefox, font-face, embedded-fonts

I've been using the service from webtype.com to render fonts on a website, but now the fonts stopped loading in Firefox (tested this on Firefox 3.6 and 4.0). It works just fine on other browsers.

After some searching, I've found that a possible explanation could be the same-origin policy in Firefox. But the only solution I've found was setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin on the server that's providing the service, to which obviously I don't have any access to.

Has anybody else encountered this problem? How did you solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the only solution, yes.  Or using a same-origin font.

If webtype.com is not returning that header, that sounds like a bug on their end that you should report to them.

Comment: No, as far as I can see they don't return the header. I've sent them a message, hopefully they'll fix this soon. Thank you.